# Recursive path counting

Tags: python, recursion, path

i am trying to count paths with a recursive function 
if for example i have the given instructions

```
instructions = {
 1: (('bot', 3), ('bot', 4)), 
 2: (('bot', 4), ('output', 0)), 
 3: (('output', 5), ('bot', 5)), 
 4: (('bot', 5), ('bot', 6)), 
 5: (('output', 1), ('bot', 7)), 
 6: (('bot', 7), ('output', 4)), 
 7: (('output', 2), ('output', 3))
}
```

`

represented by this picture 
[image]

in this in example there are `3` paths from bot `5` `(5-1, 5-7-2, 5-7-3)`. There are `6` paths from bot `4` `(4-5-1, 4-5-7-2, 4-5-7-3, 4-6-7-2, 4-6-7-3, 4-6-4)`.

this is what i have tried so far but i have no success

```
def count_path(bot, instructions):
    counter = 0
    b = "bot"
    outp = "output"
    while True:
        for x, y in instructions[bot]:
            if x == b:
                count_path(y, instructions)
            elif x == outp:
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data containing the bots and their connections?

Comment: @Ronikos What do you mean?

Comment: @Ronikos check the examples i provided it should be clear how the connections are made

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, I'm working on an answer at the moment. If you want like an idea on how to solve this, look at the coin change recursive algorithm, it has similar principles http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-coin-change-problem/

Comment: Your data structure is not clear from your diagram and your data. What is the meaning of "output" and why are they numbered? Why does the diagram have arrows from undefined numbered objects to some of your nodes? Why do numbers 1 through 6 have three meanings in your diagram and two in your data? Are we suppose do ignore all those issues? Is it guaranteed that your data dictionary has consecutive positive integers as keys, 2-tuples of 2-tuples as values, etc.? And so on. Please *explain* your data structure.

Comment: @EmettSpeer I do not understand what you are talking about. If you think about it they work on the same principles, you are calculating the number of viable paths recursively - although I understand that this may not be simple to see for some people in the coin change recursion algorithm

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity, I changed the names from bot to node - representing a point that connects forward to other points, and output to end - representing a point that does not connect forward

```
instructions = {1: (('node', 3), ('node', 4)),
            2: (('node', 4), ('end', 0)),
            3: (('end', 5), ('node', 5)),
            4: (('node', 5), ('node', 6)),
            5: (('end', 1), ('node', 7)),
            6: (('node', 7), ('end', 4)),
            7: (('end', 2), ('end', 3))}

def count_path(current_node, instructions):

    connections = instructions[current_node]

    paths = 0

    for connection in connections:

        if connection[0] == "node":
            paths += count_path(connection[1])
        elif connection[0] == "end":
            paths += 1

    return paths
```

Basically, the recursion works by checking to see if points that connect to the current point are `"node"` or `"end"`, if they are nodes, a new stack is created (ie. the function is called again) but starting from the nodes that connect to the new current node, it then checks if those points that connect to the new nodes are also nodes.

This continues until a `"end"` is reached. When this occurs it `1` is added to `paths`. The number of paths reached in the current stack are this returned to the stack above.

Recursion can be hard to visualise, but essentially as you reach end points and move back up the stacks, you are returning the total number of end points in that direction, and the top stack will therefore return the total number of end points (which is equivalent to the total number of paths).

Comment: This works but only for these instructions, as you can I have the instructions as arg meaning they can change

Comment: @HappyUnicorn I do not understand what you mean, provided the instructions are still in the same format the code can be changed to accommodate.

Comment: `def count_path(bot, instructons ):` meaning the instructions given in the example won't be always same, they can change to something else, for example `{0: (('output', 2), ('output', 0)), 1: (('output', 1), ('bot', 0)), 2: (('bot', 1), ('bot', 0))}`

Comment: This is easy to fix, simply add `instructions` as an argument to `def count_path(bot, instructions)`. I've also optimised the code so that it will still work if more than two points are connected to the current node

Comment: I see, however this won't work with bigger inputs, my bad I should have mention in the post

Comment: @HappyUnicorn how do you mean it won't work with a larger input?

Comment: Larger instructions

Comment: @HappyUnicorn It's been changed so it can handle nodes with larger instructions, if anything it will handle larger instructions better. Unless you can explain why, then I'll be happy to try and optimize it

Comment: I was thiking with memoization

Comment: I see but this way it would take too much time

Comment: @HappyUnicorn there's no need to use memoization. The reason you would use it is if the same paths could be taken twice. Memoization would allow you to see already calculated paths so you wouldn't have to calculate it twice, although in this situation there is no use for it seeing as you will never need to calculate a path twice in one path

Comment: @HappyUnicorn I believe all of these answers work the same way and the best and worst case time would be the same for them all

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the returned value from count_path and remove the `while = true`.

```
def count_path(bot, instructions):
counter = 0
b = "bot"
outp = "output"
for x, y in instructions[bot]:
    if x == b:
        counter += count_path(y, instructions)
    else:
        counter += 1
return counter
```

In *Recursion* you have a base case which in your case is when you meet a dead end i.e. an `output` element.

Lets suppose you are at bot `a`, if next element is bot `b`, then

`no. path from bot a += no. of paths from bot b`

Otherwise if the next element is a output, then add one because that is a termination of one of the paths you are counting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple but working solution. However it only counts paths but not collect them.

```py
instructions = {
 1: (('bot', 3), ('bot', 4)),
 2: (('bot', 4), ('output', 0)),
 3: (('output', 5), ('bot', 5)),
 4: (('bot', 5), ('bot', 6)),
 5: (('output', 1), ('bot', 7)),
 6: (('bot', 7), ('output', 4)),
 7: (('output', 2), ('output', 3))
}

def count_paths(bot):
    n_paths = 0
    entry = instructions[int(bot)]
    for path_type, bot_number in entry:
        if path_type == 'output':
            n_paths += 1
        elif path_type == 'bot':
            n_paths += count_paths(bot_number)

    return n_paths


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = input("Count path for: ")
    paths = count_paths(bot)
    print("For bot {bot} there are {paths} paths".format(bot=bot, paths=paths))
```